# RxJs stream termination

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm new to RxJS and curious about such an issue. Suppose I have this code:

```
 function getStream(target, event) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromEventPattern(
        function (h) {
            target.on(event, h);
        },
        function (h) {
            target.off(event, h);
        }
    );
}

function setPosition(target, point) {
    target.css({
        top: `${point.top}px`,
        left: `${point.left}px`
    });
}

function getPosition(event) {
    return {
        x: event.pageX,
        y: event.pageY
    };
}

var dragTarget = $("#dragMe");
var dropTarget = $(".dropTarget");

var mouseDown = getStream(dragTarget, "mousedown");
var mouseMove = getStream(dragTarget, "mousemove");
var mouseUp = getStream(dragTarget, "mouseup");
var mouse = mouseDown
    .map((e) => {
        return getPosition(e);
    })
    .flatMap((initialPosition) => {
        return mouseMove.map((e) => {
            var currentPosition = getPosition(e);
            return {
                top: currentPosition.y - initialPosition.y,
                left: currentPosition.x - initialPosition.x
            };
        }).takeUntil(mouseUp.merge(inDropArea));
    });
var coordinates = mouseDown
    .flatMap(() => {
        return mouseMove.map((e) => {
            return $(e.target).offset();
        }).takeUntil(mouseUp);
    });
var inDropArea = coordinates
    .filter((pos) => {
        var dropOffset = dropTarget.offset();
        return pos.left > dropOffset.left && pos.top > dropOffset.top;
    });

mouse.subscribe((val) => setPosition(dragTarget, val));
inDropArea.subscribe((pos) => {
    console.log(pos);
});
```

It's all about dragging a div element. So the question is why the "mouse" stream (or to be more specific the stream that is return to flatMap) doesn't complete when I hit drop area?
[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mdbps3uo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the stream

`mouseMove.map((e) => {
            return $(e.target).offset();
        }).takeUntil(mouseUp);`?

That stream really should terminate on `mouseup`. What will not terminate is `coordinates` as `mouseDown` will not terminate, and `flatMap` does not cause termination.

Same goes for

`mouseMove.map((e) => {
            var currentPosition = getPosition(e);
            return {
                top: currentPosition.y - initialPosition.y,
                left: currentPosition.x - initialPosition.x
            };
        }).takeUntil(mouseUp.merge(inDropArea));`

`mouse` does not terminate as `mouseDown` does not, and `map` and `flatMap` do not cause termination (unlike other operators like `take`, `first` etc.). When a new `mousedown` event will happen, `mouse` will emit anew values from the observable emitted by the `flatMap`.

How is the termination or non-termination of that stream is an issue for your use case?

Comment: I meant the second piece of code. As far as i understand mapped mouseMove stream should be emitting values until some value will appear in the stream it's "takingUntil", so it is either "mouse up" event or some value appearing in inDropArea stream. So this stream completes with mouseUp but why it isn't with value produced in inDropArea?

Comment: Two advices : 1. make a jsbin or jsfiddle so people can check your claims. 2. Make abundant use of the `tap` operator to spy on what is being passed in the streams. Also you can set a handler for the `completed` event, so you can trace that. Otherwise, yes, `mouseMove` should finish if a value is emitted by `inDropArea`, so if it does not, it is because it is finished before (by a value in `mouseup` for instance) or `inDropArea` does not produce a value. There are not many possibilities so trace it with the ideas thereaforementioned. Come back with what you found.

Answer (score 0):

`mouse` will not terminate because `mouseDown` will not terminate. When you perform a `flatMap` what you are really doing is saying, every time an event passes through here, I will be generating a new `Observable` stream, further, I would like each of those `Observables` to be *flattened* so that observers of my stream will only see the results of those sequences.

So unless the internal stream generates an error, the overall sequence will not terminate until the outer `Observable`, that is, `mouseDown` completes (which as stated will not happen because `mouseDown` is essentially and infinite stream).